# How can I capture keyboard events (keypress,keyup, ) while dragging an image,bookmark

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, keyboard, jquery-events

```
$(element).bind("dragover", function () {
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        console.log(e.which + ": " + String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    });
}
```

I cannot detect the keypress events once I start dragging. 
Is there another way to detect the keyboard inputs?

Comment: if you bind the keypress events outside the dragover binding, would that do ?

Answer (score 0):

Events like dragging an image, bookmark (which are not explicitly set to be draggable) and other modal dialogs like `alert()` and `confirm()` are known to "pause" the the event listening activity as well as any timers that are running in that context.

That said, you might want to look into the `setCapture()` method.
It turns mouse capture on for a specified element.

In other words, it redirects all mouse events to a specified DOM element until a call to `.releaseCapture()` is made.

It is traditionally used in drag-drop scenarios.

Passing `true` as parameter will let current element (if a container) capture all mouse events. i.e. cause the parent container to intercept events.

Passing `false` will let mouse events reach their intended targets before bubbling.

These below links are a good starting-point..

http://blog.stchur.com/category/advanced-javascript/page/2/

http://javascript.gakaa.com/object-setcapture-4-0-5-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Binding the event didnt work...tried with keypress,keydown,keyup
SetCapture is just for IE, but I need it to be compatible with Chrome.
I am trying something with addEventListener, but I am stuck with it...
If I find the solution, I will post it